# Error initialize process greenplum major upgrade 5.29.12 to 6.25.2 on centos 7

Tags: database, upgrade, data-warehouse, greenplum

We have a problem when Upgrade main greenplum version 5.29.12 to 6.25.2 on centos 7, when our initialization process has failed in substep saving_source_cluster_config. you can see the cli.log for detail process
cli.log :

```
[INFO]: Verifying source and target cluster versions...                    [SKIPPED]    
[INFO]: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]: Saving source cluster configuration...                             [IN PROGRESS]
[INFO]: Executing: "/opt/greenplum-db-5.29.12/bin/postgres --gp-version"
[INFO]: connecting to source cluster with: "postgresql://localhost:5432/template1?search_path="
[INFO]: Executing: "/opt/greenplum-db-5.29.12/bin/postgres --gp-version"
[INFO]: Saving source cluster configuration...                             [FAILED]     
[INFO]: Saving source cluster configuration...                             [5m1s]
[INFO]: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]: Initialize                                                         [5m1s]
[INFO]: substep "saving_source_cluster_config": 5m0s timeout exceeded waiting for all segments to be up, in their preferred roles, and synchronized.
```

We've tried to add time out in postgres.conf dan we cek the status all segments already up